# Why does MS Access not show table column 'X'?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a column named 'Shift' in my MS Access table.

This column, however, does not display in the table's view.

I can write a query to filter on the Shift column (like show all `WHERE Shift='1'`), and the query works, but the column is never visible through the MS Access interface.

[image: screenshot]

It doesn't hurt anything, but it is really frustrating that I can't get it to display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you accidentally hide it, try this steps

- On the `Format` menu, click `Unhide Columns`.
- In the *Unhide Columns dialog box*, select the names of the columns that you want to show.

Comment: That could be it. This table was designed about 15 years ago and started with a MS Excel workbook. Today, I've got MS Office Pro 2010 installed which has the ribbon buttons. So, where would the `Format` menu be? (please)

Comment: Honestly, im also not familiar with ribbon that's why i installed this addin to bring back the old menu style..hehe http://www.addintools.com/documents/word/where-format.html

Comment: That free tool did it! I don't know who hid it or why, but that removed the setting. Thank you, Kuya!